# How to set Django to read static files store in static subfolder from template

Tags: django

I trying to get image to template with static, if I use below it works.

```
<img src="{% static "images/capture.jpg" %}" alt="working image"/>
```

**But** I want to be able to do this below without type sub folder "images/"

```
<img src="{% static "capture.jpg" %}" alt="notworking image"/>
```

Here's what I have in my setting

dash>static>images>capture.jpg 
dash>static>css>mystyle.css  
dash>templates>dash>home.html

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
      ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        # os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../dash/static',),   # ( Got same result as below )
        os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),            # ( ok )
    )
```

From reading the documentation ; I have tried to use code below in my setting , but it didn't work - not sure if I am missing something here. Any recommendation would be great :

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join('static'),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by putting the images folder explicitly in the settings like:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../dash/static',),
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../dash/static/images',),
)
```

But I would advise against doing that. You should have a single `static` folder where all your static files, which contain images, css-files and also javascript-files are in the respective subfolders.

Djangos default is also to look in the static-folder of every subapp.

I have the following settings in settings.py file and it just works:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
)
```

I would not mess with that unless you have a very good reason.